# Objective C - Multi line string using stringByAppendingFormat

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, spacing

I'm having an issue with the following code. I want the resultant `multiLineTitle` to look like this

```
Each
Word
Should 
Have 
Its 
Own 
Line
```

But when I run this program, `multiLineTitle` ends up `null`. Can anyone spot the issue?

```
    NSString *title = "Each Word Should Have Its Own Line";
    NSString *multiLineTitle;

    NSArray *words = [title componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    words = [words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"]];

    for (int len = 0; len < [words count]; len++){
        multiLineTitle = [multiLineTitle stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@ \n", words[len]];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign empty string to `multiLineTitle` or allocate memory for multiLineTitle.

```
NSString *multiLineTitle = @"";
```

or

```
NSString *multiLineTitle = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
solution....
NSString *title =@"Each Word Should Have Its Own Line";
    NSMutableString *multiLineTitle =[[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    NSArray *words = [title componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    words = [words filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"]];

    for (int len = 0; len < [words count]; len++){
     [multiLineTitle appendFormat:@"%@\n",[words objectAtIndex:len]];

    }
    NSLog(@"multiLineTitle:%@",multiLineTitle);




ans:
multiLineTitle:Each
Word
Should
Have
Its
Own
Line
```